# An error occurred while sending the request. System.Net.Http

Tags: http, request

I am loading 20 items for a list. The informations I need are from Instagram. So I send some requests but I get random errors sometimes. Not every time. Do you know what could cause the random error? Maybe the asnc task to request all the 20 items at a time?

I use Visual Studio 2015, Windows 10, Universal Windows App.

**Error Code:**

```
An error occurred while sending the request.

   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Instalike.InstagramAPI.<SendAsync>d__4`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Instalike.InstagramAPI.<getProfilePicURLAndNameByID>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Instalike.MainViewModel.<>c__DisplayClass50_1.<<LoadChartsData>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Instalike.MainViewModel.<LoadChartsData>d__50.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Instalike.ChartsList.<ChartsList_Loaded>d__6.MoveNext()
```

**This is the code:**

ChartsList.xaml.cs

```
public ChartsList()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            //Frame mainFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            //mainFrame.ContentTransitions = null;
            //mainFrame.ContentTransitions = new TransitionCollection { new PaneThemeTransition { Edge = EdgeTransitionLocation.Left } };
            DataContext = App.ViewModel;
        }

        private async void ChartsList_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (await MainPage.ReadToken() != null)
            {
                if (apiClient2 == null)
                {
                    await LoadData();
                }
                if (!App.ViewModel.IsChartsDataLoaded)
                {
                    setProgressIndicator(true);
                    bool successfull = false;
                    try
                    {
                        await App.ViewModel.LoadChartsData();
                        successfull = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)  // Here the exception gets catched!
                    {
                        successfull = false;
                        //throw;
                    }
                    setProgressIndicator(false);
                    if (successfull && !App.ViewModel.IsChartsDataLoaded)
                    {
                        MainPage.tokenDeleted = false;
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Authentication));
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(Authentication));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Wird aufgerufen, wenn diese Seite in einem Frame angezeigt werden soll.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Ereignisdaten, die beschreiben, wie diese Seite erreicht wurde.
        /// Dieser Parameter wird normalerweise zum Konfigurieren der Seite verwendet.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }
```

The LoadChartsData() method:

```
public async Task LoadChartsData()
        {
           ........

            try
            {
                ChartsViewCache = await table
                    .Take(20)
                    .Skip(0)
                    //.Where(item => item.likes > 0)
                    .OrderByDescending(item => item.likes)
                    .ToCollectionAsync();
            }
            catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException exc)
            {
                MessageDialogHelper.Show(exc.Message, ResourceLoaderHelper.getString("msgErrorLoadingChartsTitle"));
            }
            if (ChartsViewCache != null)
            {
                BadgeHelper badgeHelper = new BadgeHelper();
                var tasks = new List<Task>();
                foreach (var item in ChartsViewCache)
                {
                    var thisTask = Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        string[] profileInfos = await apiClient.getProfilePicURLAndNameByID(item.userid); // This one can cause the exception!!!!!
                        item.profilePicURL = profileInfos[0];
                        item.username = profileInfos[1];
                        string[] relationship = await apiClient.getRelationshipByID(item.userid); // But these can cause it too!! Let's focus on the first one.
                        MobileServiceCollection<Badge, Badge> badge = await badgeHelper.readBadge(item.userid);
                        int[] followsAndViews = await getFollowCountAndViewsByID(item.userid);
                        item.followcount = followsAndViews[0];
                        item.views = followsAndViews[1];

                       .........

                    });
                    tasks.Add(thisTask);
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                ChartsView = ChartsViewCache;
            }
            if (ChartsView != null)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ChartsView");
                this.IsChartsDataLoaded = true;
            }
        }
```

The getProfilePicURLAndNameByID() Method:

```
public async Task<string[]> getProfilePicURLAndNameByID(string id)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, apiBaseUrl + "/users/" + id + "?access_token=" + apiAccessToken);
            var picResponse = await SendAsync<InstagramResponseProfilePicURLByID>(request);
            string[] result = { "bad", "bad" };
            if (picResponse != null)
            {
                if (picResponse.data != null)
                {
                    result[0] = picResponse.data.profile_picture;
                    result[1] = picResponse.data.username;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

And now the SendAsync() Method:

```
 private async Task<T> SendAsync<T>(HttpRequestMessage request) where T : class
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

            //TODO: Error Handling
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseBody);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: I have the same issue. were you able to resolve this?